# numpy.gradient : invalid number of arguments (Error)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using `np.gradient` function for an 2D array `(Ty)` which has a dimension of `(552,552)`.

My spacing distances `dx` are varying **(2D array)** over the grid point. `dx` dimension is also `(552,552)`.

When I apply the function as following :

```
dTydx = np.gradient(Ty, dx)[-1]     # where [-1] is the (x-dimension)
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: invalid number of arguments
```

However when I apply the same function with `dx` as a **scalar** it works.

Comment: It probably expects from you `gradient(Ty, dx1, dx2, dx3)`.

Comment: You mean by **dx1** the first dimension for **dx** ?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the gradient in a particular direction in the arrays or are you trying to calculate the gradient on both directions?

Comment: Just in a particular direction which is the (dx) that represent longitude in my array (Ty) !